# Using will_paginate without active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Presenter:

## app/presenters/games_presenter.rb

```
class GamesPresenter

  attr_reader :games, :next_page, :previous_page

  def initialize json
    @games = json['machine-games']

    paging = json['paging']
    if paging && paging['next']
      next_page_query = paging['next'].match(/\?.*/)[0]
      @next_page = "/machine_games/search#{next_page_query}"
    end

    if paging && paging['previous']
      previous_page_query = paging['previous'].match(/\?.*/)[0]
      @previous_page = "/machine_games/search#{previous_page_query}"
    end
  end

end
```

controller action :

```
def show
  # ...
  @presenter = GamesPresenter.new(json)
end
```

views:

```
<% @presenter.games.each do |game| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Previous", @presenter.previous_page %>
<%= link_to "Next", @presenter.next_page %>
```

And in order to tell Rails to load the apps/presenters/ directory along with models/, controllers/, views/, etc. add this to config/application.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.config.paths.add 'app/presenters', :eager_load => true
end
```

I would just like to know how i could go about using will_paginate for the above case? .Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `@presenter.games` is an Array, try this:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'will_paginate'


# /config/initializers/will_paginate_array.rb

require 'will_paginate/collection'

Array.class_eval do
  def paginate(page = 1, per_page = 15)
    page = 1 if page.blank? # To fix weird params[:page] = nil problem
    WillPaginate::Collection.create(page, per_page, size) do |pager|
      pager.replace self[pager.offset, pager.per_page].to_a
    end
  end
end


# /app/controllers/games_controller.rb

def show
  @presenter = GamesPresenter.new(json)
  @games = @presenter.games.paginate(params[:page], 5)
end


# /app/views/games/index.html.erb

<% @games.each do |game| %>
  ...
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @games %>
```

This basically adds the `.paginate` method to all arrays. More docs on this can be found at https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply . But i am getting wrong no. of arguments(2 for 1 ) on line @games = @presenter.games.paginate(params[:page], 5)... Would you have any idea as to why ?

Comment: Try restarting your rails server. The initializer might not be loaded. If that's not it then check what `@presenter.games` is. If it's an array, `@presenter.games.class.name` should return `"Array"`.

Comment: That fixed it ..Thanks and it does return an array ..however i still don't know why its passing in nil (can't convert nil into Integer)

Comment: I had a similar problem until I restarted the server. Is everything working fine now?

Comment: yeah i restarted the server but but still  params[:page] is nil...It gives me an error of (can't convert nil into Integer) . This happens even after i restart the error.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try adding `page = 1 if page.blank?` to the top of the `paginate` method

Comment: But that would only give the first page result rite ?

Comment: If `params[:page]` is blank, then yes. If it's not blank, then it will return whatever page `params[:page]` equals.

Comment: yeah i mean even changing the pages only the first 100 results are getting split ..but i can't seem to get the next results

Comment: Can you post your JSON and full error message to a Gist or Pastie - https://gist.github.com/ or http://pastie.org/

Comment: http://pastie.org/6461621 here is the Json skeleton .... and i do not get any error message ..I get the results to be displayed but only the first 100

Comment: Sorry, I've misread the question and assumed the JSON had all the results. I didn't realise the JSON was already paginated. My solution will not work for the JSON example and I'm not sure `will_paginate` will work for already paginated JSON. If you can get the JSON without pagination, my solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found something simplest solution.

Create file config/initializers and just require 'will_paginate/array' as:

`require 'will_paginate/array'`

Also you can require it on any other appropriate file also. It'll work on any array.

Hope it will help.

Thanks -- [**TechBrains**](http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/)